# Compare Scanned Images and detect very small visible changes

Tags: opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, emgucv

I need a solution to compare two scanned images.
I have an image of an application form (unfilled), I need to compare that against other images of the same form, and want to detect whether there is any totally unfilled application form.

I just tried with Emgu CV AbsDiff, MatchTemplate etc, but none of them give me a 100 % match, even if I scanned the same form twice in the same scanner, could be because of the noise in the scanning, I can apply a tolerance but the problem is that I need to find out whether the user has filled anything in it. If I apply a tolerance then small changes in the form will not be detected.

I also had a look at the Python Image Libray, Accord.Net etc but couldn't find an approach for comparing this type of image.

Any suggestions on how to do this type of image comparison ?
Is there any free or paid library available for this ?

Comment: How about showing us some images?

Comment: I tried to upload images but failed because I am not reputed enough, I should have 10 points :(

Answer (score 1):

Only inspect the form fields. Without distractions it's easier to detect small changes. You also don't have to inspect each pixel. Use the histogram or mean color. I used SimpleCV:

```
from SimpleCV import *

form = Image("form.png")
form_field = form.crop(34, 44, 200, 30) 
mean_color = form_field.meanColor()[0] # For simplicity only red channel.

if mean_color < 253:
    print "Field is filled"
else:
    print "Field is empty"
```

Alternatively look for features. E.g. corners, blobs or key points. Key points will ignore noise and will work better with poor scans:

```
key_points = form_field.findKeypoints()

if key_points:
    print "Field is filled"
    key_points.show(autocolor=True)
else:
    print "Field is empty"
```

Comment: It might also be reasonable to re-scale the intensity of the images so the contrast is in the same range. This will help in cases where the scanner made the image too dark or too light overall.

Comment: @wbest: For the mean color threshold you're right. Making sure paper white is actually white will ease process. But be careful manipulating the image. Don't filter out useful information. That's why `findKeypoints()` is cool. Keypoints are unique regions in an image that demonstrate some degree of invariance to changes in illumination. They don't care about optimal brightness/contrast/color.